# SQL - Multiple select statements, one column, one query

Tags: sql, select, join

I have a table called person, which has a primary key called person_id. The person table contains information about patients and doctors (initals, last_name etc). I also have another table called appointment, which contains a doctor_id, patient_id and information about the appointment. The doctor_id and patient_id are linked to the person_id in the person table.

I need to make a query that will return the name of the doctor (using concat with initials and last_name) and the name of the patient.

I've tried using nested select statements but didn't get anywhere..

Any information would be great!

Dan

Comment: you will have to self join on the persons table twice

Comment: Either that or include selects as columns which I dislike =)

Comment: What [RDBMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system) you are using? `RDBMS` stands for *Relational Database Management System*. `RDBMS is the basis for SQL`, and for all modern database systems like MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, Oracle, MySQL, etc...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT d.initials + ' ' + d.last_name AS 'doctor name', p. initials + ' ' + p.last_name AS 'patient name'
FROM Person p
INNER JOIN appointment a
ON p.person_id = a.patient_id
INNER JOIN Person d
ON d.person_id = a.doctor_id
```

Comment: Worked perfectly when I replaced "d.initials + ' ' + d.last_name" with  "CONCAT(d.initials,' ',d.last_name)". Yours was returning 0s for some reason. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

In SQL Server, the concatenation is done by using `+` operator. So concatenation operator depends on the RDBMS you are using. (*In `MYSQL`, use `CONCAT` operator*)

Basically, you need to join table `person` twice on table `appointment` as there are two columns that are dependent on table `person`.

```
SELECT  a.*
        doc.firstName + ' ' + doc.lastName as DoctorName,
        pat.firstName + ' ' + pat.lastName as PatientName
FROM    appointment a
        INNER JOIN person doc
            ON a.person_ID = doc.doctor_ID
        INNER JOIN person pat
            ON a.person_ID = pat.patient_ID
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, and the link. Need to get my head around joins.

Comment: since you are using `MySQL`, it should be `CONCAT(doc.firstName, ' ', doc.lastName)`

Answer (score 0):

Start here:

```
select 
  patient.person_id, 
  doctor.person_id
from person as patient
left join appointment 
    on appointment.patient_id = patient.person_id
left join person as doctor 
    on doctor.person_id = appointment.doctor_id 
   and doctor.person_id = patient.doctor_id
```